# Memory allocation issue in cake php while uploading a large image

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I trying upload a large image more 5MB load function through an error can't allocate memory in cake PHP. Also getting error of too large variable. I have increase max execution time and memory_limit, But doesn't work.

```
  $content = file_put_contents("file_path", $xmlvar);
            $doc = new \DOMDocument;
            $doc->load(file_path);
            $book = $doc->documentElement;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini file, specifically the settings for post_max_size and upload_max_filesize and set them to the largest size you want the server to accept.

Comment: Make sure you restart your web server after any php.ini changes.